# AngularJS don't trigger outer click event (nested ng-click)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, event-propagation

```
<ul>
    <li ng-init="hide1={state1:true}" ng-repeat="(id,name) in tree_root_list" ng-click="click_e_s_0(id,hide1)">
        {$ name[1] $}
        <ul ng-hide=hide1.state1>
            <li ng-init="hide2={state2:true}" ng-repeat="id in e_s_1" ng-click="click_e_s_1(hide2)">
                &ensp;{$ id $}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I trigger the `click_e_s_1(hide2)` event, Angular calls the `click_e_s_0(id,hide1)` event.

Actually I don't want to trigger `click_e_s_0(id,hide1)` event.

Comment: This is not an Angular2 question, please remove the tag.

Comment: Provide the code of your functions in scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actutally trying to trigger a `ng-click` (`click_e_s_1`) imbricated in another `ng-click` (`click_e_s_0`). If you want to trigger only the imbricated one, you need to [**stop the propagation**](https://benohead.com/angularjs-stopping-event-propagation-on-ng-click/) of the parent:

## Inline solution

```
<li ... ng-click="click_e_s_1(hide2); $event.stopPropagation()">
```

## In function solution

```
<li ... ng-click="click_e_s_1(hide2, $event)">
```

And update `click_e_s_1`:

```
$scope.click_e_s_1 = function(hide2, $event) {
    $event.stopPropagation(); 
    // Your stuff   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ng-click="click_e_s_1(hide2, $event)"
```

and in the click_e_s_1 function, use

```
$event.stopPropagation();
```